# How to debug react in vs code ? Error break point set but not yet bound

Tags: reactjs, debugging, visual-studio-code

I created react website and running it using gulp. I would like to debug it using VS code however I am getting warning when I set break point. What could be the issue here ? All my code is inside c:\psadmin\src folder.

> Unverified breakpoint. Break point set but not yet bound.

My launch.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:9005",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```

My Local directory

[image]

Comment: Hey Zeus did you solve this issue? can you answer your own question please if you already go a solution for this, I have the same issue right now

Comment: Were you guys able to solve this? I also have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, although I was using Webpack. You should just be able to set the webRoot to the entry point your gulp configuration uses. For example, my Webpack config entry point was `src/entry.js` so my launch config is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Chrome",
          "type": "chrome",
          "request": "launch",
          "url": "http://localhost:8089/#/",
          "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src/entry.js"
      }
  ]
}
```